# How to set DPI scale to less than 100% on Windows 10 - With multiple displays

Tags: windows, windows-10, registry, scaling, dpi

So I have a big 32 inch display with a resolution of 1440p, and I want to set the DPI scaling to 75% instead of 100%. But I can't find any way to do so on multiple monitors.

I currently have:

- Display 1 [2560 x 1440] (Main display I want to change)
- Display 2 [2560 x 1440] (This one is 27 inches so it's fine as is)
- Display 3 [3840 x 2160] (Set to 100%, fine as it is)

[This trick (click me)](https://superuser.com/questions/1328938/scale-100-on-windows-10#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20Registry%2C%20navigate%20to,is%20%22100%25%20scaling%22.) changes DPI scaling via some registry keys (LogPixels & Win8DpiScaling), but when I use that trick it downscales display 3 instead of display 1.

Is there a way to get this to work? I see no reason for Microsoft to limit the scaling in displays.

*Note: I have a 2070 super, all the displays are plugged into the GPU via displayport directly, with the latest avalible firmware at the time of writing (september 2021)*

Comment: This has been the case for ages - the only ~technical~ reason I can think of is that 100% scaling likely uses the smallest base image _(e.g. Explorer and Taskbar icons)_ resources included in various applications. Going below that point may cause small UI text and icons, such as the 'Windows' icon to loose too much detail. Taken to the extreme, the UI ~might~ become so unreadable that the user is effectively prevented from being able to read the text even in the 'Settings' window and therefore is 'stuck': i.e. not able to navigate to restore the original '100%' scaling mode.

Comment: Imagine how Windows might look displayed on one of those cheapo '1080p-supported' projectors that actually only contains an imager with a native pixel resolution of, say, 1024x576 _(or even 480x234)_. Windows thinks it can send 1080p, since that what the HDMI connection advertises, so it does, but any text / vector content looks atrocious. At least in that case the user could unplug the projector and reconnect to a normal monitor to restore functionality. Additionally, fonts usually contain a ~lot~ of manual tweaking / hints to enable readable display for very small point sizes.

Comment: **See also:** [Scale < 100% on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1328938/scale-100-on-windows-10)  and [How to setup custom DPI below 100% on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/80151/how-to-setup-custom-dpi-below-100-on-windows-7) *(superuser.com)*

Answer (score 7):

##### The tl;dr:

Technical limitations aside, there are *very solid user experience reasons* why this probably isn't allowed.

**No, Windows will *not* let you set UI scaling *below 100%*.**
*(even if a stable workaround were to be discovered, most users would probably be quite unhappy with the results)*

While I would love¹ to be proven incorrect, the implications of scaling at less than 100% are *so fraught* that this limitation is unlikely to change in the near future.

---

##### Background:

This has been the case for *ages*, likely since Windows first introduced the feature.

###### Compatibility with current software

The only ~purely technical~ reason I can think of:

- The *100% scaling size* likely uses the smallest base image *(e.g. Explorer and Taskbar icons, mouse and text cursors)* resources included in various existing Microsoft and 3rd-party applications.

###### User experience

Going below the 100% point may cause small UI text and icons, especially in application toolbars and the *Taskbar* to be blurred to the point of ambiguity.

- Those fine lines in the taskbar *'Windows'* menu icon? Blurred or gone.

Taken to the extreme, the UI ~might~ become *so unreadable* that the user is effectively prevented from being able to read the text even in the 'Settings' window and therefore is 'stuck': i.e. not able to navigate through 'Settings' to restore the original '100%' scaling mode.

- *(Luckily, Windows is never used to run any SCADA software where confusing two icons could theoretically cost money or lives.)*

###### Performance:

Since those carefully-designed graphic assets don't exist, if sub-100% scaling *were* allowed, it would also likely cause extra CPU/GPU workload - that is why only certain fixed sizes of up-sampling are shown on the normal *Display* settings screen and why the *Advanced scaling settings* screen warns that custom scaling between 100-500% is *"not recommended"*.

- That might also apply to any fixed scaling option offered below 100%, and *absolutely* would for custom scaling sizes.

###### Some people enjoy reading:

Vector-based TrueType/OpenType fonts usually contain a ~lot~ of manual tweaking / hints to enable readable display of very small point sizes.

###### The marketing department & friends of the C-suite

*Could* they implement this at a limited range of options? 90%? 75%?

Perhaps - but it's extra testing for a *horrible-looking* edge case.

- The existence of the option, *even if only available as a registry hack*, might cause some people to *actually use it in kiosks and other public-facing displays*; this risks the same sort of bad PR as when a BSOD is seen on the 'arrivals' screen at a train station or airport monitor.

Combined with the first example below, even a *90%* option could cause trouble in some environments.

---

##### Example and tutorial:

1. Imagine how Windows might look displayed on one of those cheapo '1080p-supported' projectors that actually only contains an imager with a native pixel resolution of, say, 1024x576 *(or even 480x234)*.

   - Windows thinks it can send 1080p, since that what the HDMI connection advertises, so it does: any text / vector content looks *atrocious*.
   - *(At least in this case the user could normally² unplug the projector and reconnect to a normal monitor to restore functionality.)*
2. See for yourself... while connected to any monitor *(at that monitor's native resolution)*, with Windows set to 100% scaling:

   1. Open *Windows Notepad*
   2. Type or paste in any block of text
   3. Now, use the *Zoom Out* command from the *View* menu³ five or more times in a row

   - While not an *exact* analogue, you may still see how hard it could be to read down-sampled text, *even when very high-contrast (the best-case scenario)*.

---

¹: *As someone currently typing this very answer on a 1080p connection to a 55" 4K television as a second monitor, I came across the question **very much** hoping this was possible. Sadly, logic intervened and killed my potential joy.*
    ²: *Unless the computer is actually stored somewhere locked or inaccessible, such as a NUC-style PC hidden above the false ceiling in a conference room.*
    ³: *Alternatively, press `<CTRL>`-`<Minus>` five or more times.*

Comment: **See also:** [Scale < 100% on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1328938/scale-100-on-windows-10)  and [How to setup custom DPI below 100% on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/80151/how-to-setup-custom-dpi-below-100-on-windows-7) *(superuser.com)*